# Reading files in JApplet multiple times

Tags: java, bufferedreader, japplet

I don't think it is an issue with my code so I will just explain the situation and hopefully it can be cleared up. I have a JApplet that is reading a .txt file with the names of all the players. When I create a player this file is updated to add the player to the list using php, this works fine and I can read the player list from the text file when I load the applet and if I create a character the php file updates my text file instantly. If I try to read the list of players from the text file again using my same method that read it fine on start up it doesn't read the updated file.
So basically I am wondering if the applet is just preloading all the files when it starts instead of directly reading them from the webs server or web directory each time, it is saving the files in the same place as my website. If this is the case is there a way to get it to update the files. It only happens in the browser. When in eclipse it reads the changed file with no problems.

```
try{
     URL url = new URL("http://mywebsitegoeshere.com/playerNames.txt");

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

     String line = "";

     while(null != (line = br.readLine())) {
        if(line.equals(name + ".txt")){
           return true;
        }
     }
     br.close();


}catch(Exception er){}
```

This is just a short part of my code that I removed stuff from to give an idea of how I'm reading the file. I am editing the file using php and that works fine. I just need to know how the JApplet is reading my file since it reads it fine when I first read the file, then after a change to the .txt file on the web server it reads the original and not the changed.  I may just have to change how I'm storing user information I just thought this would be an easy way for this small game.

Comment: Whenever I've thought, "I don't think it is an issue with my code ...", it ultimately is an issue with my code. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: But then again, you may be right... this may be a cache issue.

Comment: Yea I only put that because it works fine in eclipse and it does read the file exactly how I wont it the first time like if I go to the highscores page I can view them but If I play and get a new highscore that one isn't displayed but if I restart browser then I can see the new one on the list.

Comment: `}catch(Exception er){}` Don't do that in code that is not working as expected.  Change it to `}catch(Exception er){ er.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: That code is just a quick example I provided to show how I am reading the file I removed most stuff from the method that had nothing to do with reading the file. It isn't giving me an error or reading the file wrong it just doesn't recognize a change to the text file while the applet is running.